# cocos2d I want my image is displayed once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have an application cocos2d. I want my image is displayed once. Not every time I go in cocos2d view.Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this ques is not explicitly related to cocos2d though.

Steps:
1. When you need to display ur image, check for a bool value existence in NSUserDefaults.
2. If value does not exists (or return value is FALSE), means you can display your image.
3. After displaying image, set TRUE value in NSUserDefaults for that specific key.

Done..!!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a global flag for this. Create a bool variable globally and set it False after display image. And check this variable each time entering that view. If it is false you can remove that image from view or set it's opacity to zero if you want to display that image in any other cases.